# Weird color on texture painting with brush

Tags: texture-painting

I'm new to Blender and was hoping someone could help me with this. I was watching a tutorial on youtube to learn texture painting in version 2.79 (as you can clearly see by incredibly amateur work, LoL) when all of a sudden the white color turned pinkish. I tried reloading a previous save, restarting blender, but unfortunately it didn't work. I checked if I'd changed the sliders by mistake, but no. Everything was as it supposed to be. I even went as far as reinstalling my gpu drivers. I've posted a picture. I hope you can see the slight difference. I know, it probably sounds like nitpicking on my side, but I can clearly see the difference in color. I'd appreciate any help. Thx in advance.  .[image]

Comment: maybe pack your images and share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you tapped it. I've been trying to recreate the pink and RED is the direction any change in Saturation goes. As I approach .03, the pink begins to stand out if I see all your other settings correctly.

I'm not sure about creating palettes and how much protection that affords from changing colors. In my opinion you took the right steps by restarting and opening a saved version. I almost want to point some blame toward the alpha but that seems pretty locked in.

Triple check that color swatch and don't get fancy with any button shortcuts while painting in case one of them toggled some setting we're not thinking of. Checking Accumulate and Add for the Blend mode might also restore white where you need it if things are still rosy.